# How can I launch the eMail client, and then do a page redirect with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mailto

I'm required to make a website function exactly the same on other browsers as it does in IE6. Part of the current code looks similar to this:

```
<script>
function myFunc(){
 location.href="mailto:test@test.com&body=Hello!";
 location.href="newPage.html";
}
</script>
<body onload="myFunc();">
</body>
```

in IE, this causes the mail client to open with the specified message prepared, and then redirects the browser to newPage.html. Other browsers, however, only redirect to newPage.html. How can I achieve this effect (opening the mail client and then doing a page redirect) consistently across browsers?
As a note, I've also tried to accomplish this using meta refresh, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `<script>` tag to `<script type="text/javascript">` to see if there is a difference?

Comment: What other browsers? it works in my FF 3.5.7.

Comment: yeah, no luck. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: I've been testing in Chrome. It doesn't seem to be working in Firefox 3.5.1 for me on this machine, though, either.

Comment: I edited my answer for a possible workaround, check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the `href` property will start a location load, changing it again afterwards will cancel the previous navigation.

It appears that IE6 will start the e-mail client immediately upon setting the property, then continue the javascript execution.  Other browsers appear to do things differently, and the second location load will cancel the first.

I managed to work around this in Chrome with a timer, it might work for other browsers too:

```
function myFunc(){ 
  location.href="mailto:test@test.com&body=Hello!"; 
  window.setTimeout(function () { location.href="newPage.html" }, 0); 
}
```

Comment: Yeesh, and he gives it to you instead of me. The bum. ;-) 32 seconds! Eons!

Comment: Stop whining, I beat you *both* by 4 minutes! :) On the other hand, @Andy E you took the time to actually test it, so the mark went to the right person.

Comment: @T.R.: And you chose the right one. @Pekka: Oh, I agree (about Andy), I'm just joking around. :-) (But for the record: I'm pretty sure I posted my answer before you edited yours.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Right, I edited mine a few minutes later, you're right.

Comment: @Pekka: You beat my answer with your edit, so it must have been really close. I have questions sorted in order of oldest so that I mark the first correct one but I supposed that doesn't always work with edits.  @T.J. Crowder: I knew you were joking ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Try using something like:

```
<a href="mailto:mail@domain.com" onclick="window.location.href='np.html'">send</a>
```

Instead of at the onload.

Comment: On now *that's* smart. But I'd include a slight delay before changing the window location in the `onclick` handler.

Comment: Generally speaking, I actually much prefer this solution, but in this specific case I think it's better for me to stick with the javascript based solution.

Comment: Nice solution, indeed. But please don't forget the final " after the second url. ;)

Comment: @Marcel I added the missing "

Answer (score 4):

On the whole, I tend to think security settings will get in your way and would recommend just giving the user a boring old-fashioned `mailto` link to click. (Edit: Perhaps one set up like Mic suggests.)

That said, I wonder if things become any more reliable if you introduce a delay:

```
function myFunc() {
    location.href = "mailto:test@test.com&body=Hello!";
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "newPage.html";
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work only if the client's browser knows which E-Mail client to open for `mailto:` links in the first place. If the user uses a web-based client that is not registered with the browser, nothing will happen.

Also, it could be that security settings prevent `mailto:` links from opening programmatically, or will prevent it in the future.

I wouldn't rely on this to work either way, only as a nice optional convenience function.

Anyway, to answer your question, can you try setting a timeout between the two calls? Maybe the location refresh is just too quick for the browser to catch up.

```
location.href="mailto:test@test.com&body=Hello!";
setTimeout(function(){ location.href = 'newPage.html' },  500);
```

Comment: lol you beat me while I was testing my answer.  I found that a timeout interval of 0 works fine at least in Chrome.  I'm also out of votes or I would +1 :-)

Comment: LOL! That's three of us now, my friend. :-) But I still like Mic's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "index.html";
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 