# create link to users email domain php

Tags: php, email, hyperlink, email-address

User signs up on website, site sends out automated activation email and echos the following onto the signup page:

```
Thank you for signing up!
Please check your email <a href="link to email client">here</a> for an activation email...
```

Is it at all possible to create the link above by using the users email address, assuming that some users may be using a work email and not have access to it by following just the domain name after the @ symbol?

Comment: I think every user should know where to check their email, so I don’t see any point in giving that link …

Comment: Good call. I think I've put too many hours into building this damn thing today that my ideas are rapidly getting worse. :-s

Answer (score -1):

You can only open the preset mail client by a `mailto:` markup.

Since then you open a new email implicitly, this might not be what you want:

[How can I launch the eMail client, and then do a page redirect with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192860/how-can-i-launch-the-email-client-and-then-do-a-page-redirect-with-javascript)

Comment: @matt1985 Yeah I see, but what made you or somebody else downvote? This is the only right answer AFAIK. ;)

Comment: @matt1985 Haha, right. As the downvoter points out there must be a solution to this, would be helpful if he enlightened us both. ;)